# Getting the json structure of nested elements with sortable.js

Tags: sortablejs

I want to use the hierarchical nestable library. I can't get json structure of nested elements with child elements.(http://sortablejs.github.io/Sortable/#nested)

Here I want to get the nested elements created with the onEnd function as a json structure. Like here:
(https://dbushell.github.io/Nestable/).

For example: [{"id":1},{"id":2,"children":[{"id":3},{"id":4},{"id":5,"children" :[{"id":6},{"id":7},{"id":8}]},{"id":9},{"id":10}]},{"id" :11},{"id":12}].

If I can get this I will edit the database later.

I couldn't find any explanation for this either on the developer site http://sortablejs.github.io/Sortable/#nested, or on stackoverflow, nor on the developer's github page and in the comments and discussions. That's why I'm writing here.

Is there a solution?